# compactness of $\{(x,y):x^p+y^p=1\}$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I would like to know whether there is a rule other than drawing the curve to find out the set $\{(x,y):x^p+y^p=1\}$ is compact or non compact subset in $\mathbb{R}^2$

The set is closed for any values of $p\in\mathbb{R}^{+}$ right?

when $p$ is even positive integer, clearly the set is bounded and unbounded when $p$ is odd.

what about when $p$ is positive rational number and irrational number? anything can be concluded? Thank you.

Comment: How do you deal with $x^p$ when $x$ is negative and $p$ is not an integer?

Comment: When the exponent is not an integer, it’s hard to know what to do with negative bases. So I think @TaxiDriver should thing about all this rather more.

Comment: In the cases where it makes sense though, you will probably believe that $(x,y) \mapsto x^p + y^p$ is continuous and so closedness follows from the fact that your set is the preimage of the closed set $\{1\}$ under a continuous map.

Comment: OP: Any luck in making the question more precise?

Answer (score 3):

Taking a more general view, you want to know when a set $\{x\in\mathbb R^n: f(x)=c\}$ is compact, where $f:\mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R$ is continuous. The relevant term is [proper map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proper_map), which has the more general property that preimage of *every* compact set is compact.

*Fact*.  A continuous function $f:\mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R$ is proper if and only if $\lim_{|x|\to\infty} |f(x)|=\infty$.

The necessity is obvious because for every $M$ the set $\{x:|f(x)|\le M\}$ is compact. The sufficiency is best handled by passing to [one-point compactifications](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-point_compactification) of the spaces involved. The condition $\lim_{|x|\to\infty} |f(x)|=\infty$ says precisely that $f$ extends continuously to a map between compactified spaces. Its properness immediately follows, since every continuous map from a compact space to a Hausdorff space is  proper. $\quad \Box$

Returning to your situation: when $p$ is a positive even integer, the above applies. When $p$ is a positive odd integer, the map is not proper (consider $f(x,-x)=0$) which *suggests* that the compactness of other level sets might fail as well - and it does.